# assigning all numbers in a random order into 2D array from a given list

Tags: c, arrays

I have written the following program in c to distribute K numbers in arandom order into M*N (M=row,N=column) array **where K=MN**, such that each cell gets a unique number from 0 to MN. But there is a problem. I am getting some repeated numbers into sum cells. **How will I get all the unique numbers?**

Sample program:#

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<math.h>
 #include <time.h>
 #define row 5
 #define col 5
 int total=row*col;
 int A[row][col];


main()
{
    int i,j;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(i=0;i<row;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<col;j++)
    {
        A[i][j]=rand()%total+1;

    }
}

for(i=0;i<row;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<col;j++)
    {
       printf("\nA[%d][%d]=%d",i,j,A[i][j]);

    }
}

}
```

Comment: So you don't want random *numbers*, you want a random *permutation*?

Comment: yes. you are right @EOF

Comment: Set the initial numbers however, then randomize them with the fisher yates shuffle?

Comment: can you please show a demo code? @thrig

Answer (score 1):

Notice that saying "these numbers are all different" immediately makes them *less* random than saying "these numbers are random". You seem to feel that duplicates makes the collection of numbers as a whole less random, which is not true.

You seem to want a permutation. One way of achieving that is by doing random shuffles, i.e. initialize the matrix with unique numbers, then repeatedly pick two cells at random and swap their contents. There are, undoubtedly, all manner of ways of knowing when you've done "enough" swaps.

Here's how one swap could be implemented:

```
void random_point(int *x, int *y)
{
  *x = rand() % col;
  *y = rand() % row;
}

void permute(void)
{
  int x1, y1, x2, y2;
  random_point(&x1, &y1);
  random_point(&x2, &y2);
  const int tmp = A[y1][x1];
  A[y1][x1] = A[y2][x2];
  A[y2][x2] = tmp;
}
```

That's very basic.

Comment: can you show a sample code of random permutation? @unwind